# View.Activate/Deactivate event listener registered multiple times

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a simple Apache Flex view based application that runs on Android as follow:

```
<f:MyView xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/sparks"
activate="activateHandler(event)"
deactivate="deactivateHandler(event)"/>
```

I expect the `activateHandler()` should execute only once when the view is activated, however after I pop and then push the same view back the number of `activateHandler()` execution increased by how many times I did the pop and push operation. Why would this happen and how to force it to operate as expected (i.e only once)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on @JileniBouguima's answer, changing `activate` to `creationComplete` will resolve this because of how those events work.  Your expectation that `activateHandler()` executes only once is a little off; according to the [Activate event documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#event:activate), `activate` fires 
*every time* your application gains operating system focus and becomes active.

By contrast, `creationComplete` fires once per object, once the [component is created](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html#WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7ffc).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what code exactly is written in the handlers `activateHandler` and `deactivateHandler` but in Flex this is a standard practice to remove event listener if you do not need it any more. I am assuming that whenever you pop and push the same view it is adding and removing the listener. I can help you more if you share the handlers code.

Comment: let me clarify my question, I observed that the event listeners did not removed along when the view is popped. The default destruction policy should destroy the object and free resources when a view is popped off the view stack, however what I experienced was the activate handler executed once the first time, executed twice the 2nd time and so on... If the handler just have one line of code 'trace("hello")' the result will become

Answer (score 0):

Change `activate` to `creationComplete`.